# simultaneous send and receive using MPI

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I have a network where processes sends a random message to its neighbours and simultaneously receive messages from its neighbours.
I'm able to do it using sockets and threads. One thread receives messages and another sends messages to a neighbour chosen randomly. Is it possible to achieve this using MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV?

Comment: You mean the non-blocking version of send and receive?

Comment: Never mind. Actually, I don't understand your question well to answer it.

Comment: I tried using that but I need to put the send in a loop which sends messages at random intervals of time. During this execution of loop the rank should receive any message sent to it

Answer (score 1):

You can use MPI calls in a multi-threading environment. Check the manual for the [MPI_Init_thread](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Init_thread.html) function and this paper: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~thakur/papers/mpi-threads.pdf. Beware that MPI-1 standard doesn't require an implementation to be thread-safe, only MPI-2 does (but the implementation you use is most probably MPI-2).

Comment: Thanks. Is multi-threading the only option or is it theoretically possible to achieve this using non-blocking send and receive?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing in details what your code is doing, i.e. maybe it's possible to rearrange your algorithm somehow and use non-blocking calls then. On the other hand, I had very similar problem in the past - I was working on parallel sorting and it was necessary to send and to receive messages at the same time; the only solution which I found was to use two threads and sockets (it was at the time when MPI-2 did not exist yet and all MPI-1 implementations available to me were not thread-safe).

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of "simultaneous"?

In any case, you may be interested in [MPI_Sendrecv](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node45.html#SECTION00360000000000000000):

> The semantics of a send-receive operation is what would be obtained if the caller forked two concurrent threads, one to execute the send, and one to execute the receive, followed by a join of these two threads.

Comment: Thanks. Say I have 3 ranks and each rank needs to send 2 messages to other ranks. For example, Rank1 sends 2 messages to Rank0 and 2 messages to Rank1. In total each rank sends 4 messages. But the time interval between each send is randomized. And I don't want to put a synchronization block between each sendrecv.